# Generating a list of unique characters in a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, string, unicode, standards

I have a database that that contains the titles of hymns from a hymnbook that was published in 28 languages. As I typed in the titles, I researched which unicode characters were most correct in each language (for example, the Tongan glottal stop should be U+02BB even though it looks like an apostrophe; also, in Romanian, U+021A (ț) is more correct than U+0163 (ţ), etc.).

Now I am working on a similar project and I want to go back and "decompose" my research by gathering all the titles in a single language and outputting a list of all the unique characters that were used in the titles.

Is there a way to do this with MySQL and/or Python? I'm thinking something that splits a string between every character, orders all the characters, and groups them together. My web site is in Python but it is all very basic coding (I'm not too advanced yet).

---

**Edit: This is how my code turned out in the end, thanks to these responses, and it works well!**

```
hymnstitleslist = lookup('''
  SELECT HyName FROM Hymns
  WHERE HymnbookID = "'''+hbid+'''"
''')
import string
from collections import Counter
some_text = ""
for x in range(0, len(hymnstitleslist)):
  some_text = some_text+hymnstitleslist[x]['HyName']
letters = []
for i in some_text:
  letters.append(i)
letter_count = Counter(letters)
for letter,count in letter_count.iteritems():
  print "{}: {}".format(letter,count)
```

Comment: Can you explain the second paragraph? somehow what i got is that in one column you will save the titles in one language and in another you want to save unique characters?

Comment: @RahulJha, I need some code that will take in a list of titles and give me a list of the unique characters in those titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm thinking something that splits a string between every character,
>   orders all the characters, and groups them together.

This part is easily done:

```
import string

from collections import Counter

some_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque fringilla augue ac metus laoreet quis imperdiet velit congue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque tincidunt lorem ut justo fermentum adipiscing. Nullam ullamcorper eros in arcu tincidunt non scelerisque ligula molestie. Vestibulum imperdiet facilisis nisi, et sodales leo sodales at. In hac habitasse platea dictumst."

letters = []
for i in some_text:
   # Each "i" is a letter or space
   if i in string.letters:
      # only collect letters, not punctuation marks or spaces
      letters.append(i)

# count how many of each
letter_count = Counter(letters)

# For each letter, print the count:

for letter,count in letter_count.iteritems():
    print "{}: {}".format(letter,count)
```

This will give you:

```
C: 1
I: 1
L: 1
N: 1
Q: 1
P: 1
V: 2
a: 24
c: 19
b: 5
e: 44
d: 10
g: 6
f: 4
i: 44
h: 2
j: 1
m: 17
l: 27
o: 17
n: 18
q: 4
p: 10
s: 32
r: 19
u: 34
t: 31
v: 1
```

---

> I'm pulling from a MySQL table, so my data is in a dictionary. How can
>   I combine data from all selected entries?

Well the first step would be to collect all the data into a collection of some sort, lets say a list:

```
letters = []

cur.execute(some_query) # See the Python database API for what is going on here
results = cur.fetchone()

while results:
   the_text = results[0] # if its the first column
   for i in the_text.split():
       # By default, split() will separate on whitespace,
       # so each i is a word.
       for letter in i:
           if letter in string.letters:
               letters.append(letter)

    results = cur.fetchone() # get the next result
```

Comment: I'm pulling from a MySQL table, so my data is in a dictionary. How can I combine data from all selected entries?
  hymnstitleslist = lookup('''
    SELECT HyName FROM Hymns
    WHERE HymnbookID = "'''+hbid+'''"
  ''')
  import string
  from collections import Counter
  some_text = hymnstitleslist[0]['HyName']
  letters = []
  for i in some_text:
    # Each "i" is a letter or space
    letters.append(i)
  # count how many of each
  letter_count = Counter(letters)
  # For each letter, print the count:
  for letter,count in letter_count.iteritems():
    print "{}: {}".format(letter,count)

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the code to display very well. I'll try again :)
My data is in a dictionary. How can I combine data from all selected entries?
    hymnstitleslist = lookup('''
      SELECT HyName FROM Hymns
      WHERE HymnbookID = "'''+hbid+'''"
    ''')
    import string
    from collections import Counter
    some_text = hymnstitleslist[0]['HyName']
    letters = []
    for i in some_text:
      letters.append(i)
    letter_count = Counter(letters)
    for letter,count in letter_count.iteritems():
      print "{}: {}".format(letter,count)

Comment: I ended up using a for loop to concatenate each "HyName" field in the dictionary into one big string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can split all you titles by letters and add it to set. In set you get all unique characters. And simple example is:

```
all_you_titles_string = 'title1 title2 ti tl e3'
result_set = set()
[result_set.add(letter) for letter in all_you_titles_string.replace(' ', '')]
print result_set
```

Comment: How can I get results from all the entries in a dictionary instead of just a string?

Comment: @Samuel Sorry I don't understand your question clear, try write in pseudo code what structs you have and what you want.

Comment: 1. I have this: `hymnstitleslist= lookup('''SELECT HyName FROM Hymns WHERE HymnbookID = "'''+hbid+'''"''')` 2. I don't know how to do this: `concatenate all HyNames into one string` 3. `result_set = set()...` (this is the part you showed me).

Comment: @Samuel Ok, I understand you. I don't know which mysql driver you use and what struct it's return to you, just copy and paste output from query like [('hymntitle', 'some hymn title 1'), ('hymntitle', 'some hymn title 2')] and etc.

Comment: Thanks! I used a for loop to concatenate everything into one string: `some_text = ""` **\n** `for x in range(0, len(hymnstitleslist)):` **\n** `some_text = some_text+hymnstitleslist[x]['HyName']`